# how can i get access to items (contents) on webphere web content manager

Tags: websphere-portal, lotus-wcm

Hi everybody i'm developing some specifics Websphere Portal 8 portlets and i need to get access to data on Web Content Manager (WCM). if there is a solution to get (title, content .. ) of every elements. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WCM API:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+WebSphere+Portal+8+API+and+SPI+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=IBM_Web_Content_Manager_API_specification_javadoc8&content=apicontent

Here is the link of Javadoc:

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/portal_javadoc/80/wcm/api-javadoc/index.html